# Heroku is not connecting with mongoose Atlas

Tags: github, heroku, mongoose

I created a shopping site using `node.js` and launched it on Heroku, but I face one problem:
My heroku is not connecting with mongoose atlas

However, all configuration seems right, like uri variable.

What should I do: I did not get any error.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation is art "[Using MongoDB Atlas on Heroku](https://developer.mongodb.com/how-to/use-atlas-on-heroku/)", written by [Adrienne Tacke](https://twitter.com/adriennetacke), so double-check your config (as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59587090/6309)), especially the db connection.
And, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42170205/6309), in order to do this in combination with Heroku dynos, add `0.0.0.0/0` (i.e. all addresses) to your MongoDB Atlas whitelist.

Finally, check your code (as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57411088/6309)), using `MongoClient`.

---

You have a concrete example at "[M2 - Heroku Deployment (with Mongo Atlas)](https://gist.github.com/ross-u/b59ea6a1febefb80bffc15ecf31ea827)" from [Uros Cirkovic](https://github.com/ross-u):
check your logs with `heroku logs -n 200`

[image: settings]